# minted: how to highlight java method at class

Tags: minted

I'm trying to highlight a method at a Java class with *minted*. The usual notation (at least in Javadocs) for a method at a class is classname#method, but when I do something like:

```
\mintinline{java}{public class MyClass#myMethod}
```

I get the class highlighted but the method not. Moreover, the hash turns in to a reference/link to that same spot.

How can I highlight the method too?

**Extra:** if I could somehow highlight the class without having to prepend it with `public class` would be sweet.

Comment: Java ≠ Javadoc. If you want to highlight Javadoc notation strings you need to build a custom Pygments lexer for that.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I just found out that substituting the `#` for a `@` does the trick! Not same notation as in Javadoc, but it highlights the method.

Still don't know about the *extra* part though...